# How to enable direct to agent routing from standard Einstein bot?

Tags: servicecloud, chat, einstein-chatbot, skill-based-routing, chatbot

We have a requirement to directly route the chat from Einstein bot to a specific agent linked with the Case when the user clicks on Transfer menu and Einstein bot only supports bot/queue/skill transfer.
We have tried a lot of things, including Apex class call to create/update PSR and Agentwork records but nothing seems to work. Has anybody done this? Any ideas would be much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific details of how Einstein Bot handles transfers, but I can provide some general information about how you might approach this problem.
If Einstein Bot doesn't support direct routing to a specific agent, you may need to find a workaround to achieve this functionality. One approach you could try is to use a custom Apex class to create or update a "PSR" (presumably a "Primary Service Request" record) and an "Agentwork" record, which you can use to track the transfer and route the chat to the correct agent.
To do this, you would need to create a custom Apex class that contains the logic for creating or updating the PSR and Agentwork records, and then call this class from your Einstein Bot code whenever the user clicks on the Transfer menu. You would need to pass the necessary information (such as the agent's ID and the case ID) to the Apex class so that it can properly route the chat to the correct agent.Of course, this is just one possible approach, and there may be other ways to implement this functionality in Einstein Bot.

Comment: Hi Erika, Thanks for your response! We have actually tried this- called Apex class which modifies PSR/Agentwork record with PreferredUserId but the Agentwork record remains in cancelled status and the chat never reaches the Agent's Omni console